# How to strip trailing digits from a string

Tags: python

I have a variable text whose value is like below,I need strip of trailing digits,is there a python built-in function to do it..if not,please suggest how can this be done in python

e.g. `-text=A8980BQDFZDD1701209.3` => `-A8980BQDFZDD`

Comment: Yes, there is. It's called (surprise) `strip`.

Comment: Trailing digits and the full stop? And ``"text="`` from the beginning? Your input/output doesn't match your description well.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `rstrip`. Check the python docs.

Comment: You should write your answer based on the docs instead of just pointing someone to the docs.

Answer (score 6):

For the sake of completion, how about this syntax in python3 ?

```py
from string import digits

print('123abc382'.rstrip(digits))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In [36]: myStr = '-text=A8980BQDFZDD1701209.3'

In [37]: print '-'+myStr.rpartition('=')[-1].rstrip('1234567890.')
-A8980BQDFZDD
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print '123abc382'.rstrip('1234567890')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print 'text=A8980BQDFZDD1701209.3'.rstrip('1234567890.')[5:]
```

will do everything required. The slicing at the end is something of a hack, however.

Comment: Thanks,what is the [5:] at the end do?

Comment: That takes off the `text=` part. E.g., the first 5 characters.

Comment: It looks like he wants to keep the `-` at the start, so your slicing needs a change.

Comment: Ah, the original text wasn't that clear. It wasn't obvious whether or not the `-` was part of the input. OP: If that is part, please say so.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to understand what information the strings are encoding, and how you decode it as you read it. That tells you what the patterns in your data are, and those will determine how you'll manipulate the string to extract the information in Python.

If you just need to lose the last few numbers, you could `rstrip` them easily enough. This is assuming you want to change "-text=" to  "-", as you imply in the question:

```
input = '-text=A8980BQDFZDD1701209.3'
text = input.split('=')[1]
output =  '-' + text.rstrip('1234567890.')
```

This is a potentially risky approach since it also assumes the numeric suffix will *never* have any alphabetic characters in it, and that the half you want to keep will *never* end in a character you're passing to `rstrip`. If either of those things are not always true of your data, this solution will give you bad results and you'll need to find a more accurate pattern.

For example, if the 'keep' part is *always* 12 characters long, you would want to take a string slice by replacing line 3 of my example with this:

```
output = '-' + text[:12]
```

But ultimately, it depends on what these strings are, and what rules define how the different halves are formed in the first place.